# control google street view with a game controller

Tags: google-maps, game-controller

Is there a way to control google street view with a game controller ?

Answer (score 3):

I would expect it to be possible
given that Google have demonstrated [**Wii Balance Board** to be able to control Google Earth](http://digital.venturebeat.com/2009/01/08/google-hacks-the-wii-balance-board-to-surf-google-earth-literally/).

> Using the Google Earth application programming interface (API), a Google engineer was able to get the Balance Board to talk to the program after decoding the Bluetooth packets being sent from the board (that’s how the device wirelessly interacts with a machine like the Nintendo Wii). The result ([which you can see in the video](http://www.youtube.com/v/2U794gq3_IQ&hl=en&fs=1&rel=0&color1=0x2b405b&color2=0x6b8ab6) [youtube ref]) allows users to move forward by leaning forward, move backwards by leaning back, etc.

Another reference:  [The Wiimote Google Maps combo](http://internetsiao.com/job-around-the-streets-of-tokyo-virtually-with-the-wiimote-google-maps-combo/)

> This supposedly jogging enthusiast has actually got the Wiimote to interface with Google Maps to produce a really interesting jogging simulator!
>   The system will basically display a slideshow of a continuous series of pictures taken in the Google street view based on the estimated running speed of the jogger.

Comment: Would be pretty cool if there was a Godzilla easter egg for the balance board. Bye, Japan.